# FFmpeg: Reading the source code, how do I understand the impact of a given configuring option?

Tags: configuration, ffmpeg, configure

I was trying to investigate the impact of the `--enable-gray` configuring option on the ffmpeg code. However, if I [download the source](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#get-sources) and grep the entire project for `enable-gray`, the only entry I find is in the `configure` file, in the help section. Is this option used at all? If it is used, how do I find the section of code which are activated by using this option?

Even using a regex search with `enable.*gray` doesn't bring any additional results.

Comment: Search for `CONFIG_GRAY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you need to grep `CONFIG_GRAY` in *FFmpeg* source code, as Mulvya correctly mentioned.

The reason is that *configure* script builds special `config.h` file which is used to determine enabled and disabled options.

So, in case of `--enable-gray` option *FFmpeg* deals with `CONFIG_GRAY`, which is represented if `config.h` as below:

```
#define CONFIG_GRAY 1
```

(it will be `0` if you configure without `--enable-gray`).

Grepping with `CONFIG_GRAY` we can see, that this option is used in `vc1_loopfilter.c`, `vc1_mc.c` and some other files.